# How to set the text encoding for a Room database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'd like to be able to estimate the NVM size each row in a given [Room database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) is likely to take; the values are all Strings in Java, so I need to know the encoding format that will be used for the underlying SQLite database by Room -- how can I tell Room which encoding to use (e.g. UTF-8) or check programmatically which encoding it is using for text?  Assuming the encoding is not configurable, what would it be hard-coded to?

I expected something like

```
@Database(entities = {TestEntity.class}, version = 1, encoding = "UTF-8")
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase
```

to work, but the encoding param is not recognized.

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: @10101101 nope, but https://www.sqlite.org/search?q=encoding&i=1 suggests that the default encoding for SQLite3 would be UTF-8; since Room doesn't let you set the encoding, I'm guessing they just go with the defaults so it would likely be UTF-8?

Comment: yes you are right :) I tried to go with collate in columninfo and in query but Polish chars still didnt showed... but then changed formatting of xml file (from ANSI to UTF-8 without BOM), this file is downloaded from server and later serialized and saved into room db on phone. And also changed charset encoding in input/output streams, from "UTF-8" string, into Charset.forName("UTF-8"), And this worked !!! Thank you, you put me on the right track :D

Answer (score 1):

add create callback where your room database builder and then execute `PRAGMA encoding='UTF-8';`

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
            .addCallback(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                    super.onCreate(db);
                     // add this code
                     db.execSQL("PRAGMA encoding='UTF-8';");            
                }
            }).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```